# Why replace doesn't work (doesn't replace the values)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python `3.6.8` and `pandas`.

I'm loading csv file and tying to replace strings in one of the colums with other strings.

```
import pandas as pd
INPUT_FILE = "input.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE, error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')

print(df.columns)
print ("Before: ", df['tweet'].loc[432])
dic = {":-)": "happy-smiley",
       ":)": "happy-smiley",
       ":-(": "sad-smiley",
       ":(": "sad-smiley"}

df.replace({'tweet': dic}, inplace=True)
print ("After: ", df['tweet'].loc[432])
```

output:

```
Index(['tweet', 'existence', 'existence.confidence'], dtype='object')
Before:  Are you ready for climate change, if so let your lawmakers know, how tell them sign petitions, drop a hint :)
After:  Are you ready for climate change, if so let your lawmakers know, how tell them sign petitions, drop a hint :)
```

But as you can see, I'm getting same results (the ":)" string doesn't change with "happy-smiley").

What am I missing ?

Comment: It looks for an *exact* match, not a "substring match".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in keys of dictionary  are used special regex values is possible escape them before replace and also add `regex=True` for subtrings replacement:

```
import re

dic = {re.escape(k):v for  k, v in dic.items()}
print (dic)
{':\\-\\)': 'happy-smiley', 
  ':\\)': 'happy-smiley', 
  ':\\-\\(': 'sad-smiley',
  ':\\(': 'sad-smiley'}


df.replace({'tweet': dic}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```